# How to give WMS URL for Geoserver in worldwind Android?

Tags: java, android, worldwind

How to give geoserver url for Worldwind in Android?

In desktop version I give

> http://localhost:8090/geoserver/WorldWind/wms?service=WMS

and it is working for me, but same url does not work in Qglobe Android Application code.

As it is not showing list of getcapabilities in wms and shows error in WWXML class.

[image: getcapabilities not showing]

It shows following error in console

> 02-25 14:36:35.805: W/System.err(333):     at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.WWXML.openEventReaderURL(WWXML.java:450)
>   02-25 14:36:35.805: W/System.err(333):  at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.WWXML.openEventReader(WWXML.java:491)
>   02-25 14:36:35.805: W/System.err(333):  at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.WWXML.openEventReader(WWXML.java:466)
>   02-25 14:36:35.815: W/System.err(333):  at gov.nasa.worldwind.ogc.OGCCapabilities.createReader(OGCCapabilities.java:91)
>   02-25 14:36:35.815: W/System.err(333):  at gov.nasa.worldwind.ogc.OGCCapabilities.(OGCCapabilities.java:72)
>   02-25 14:36:35.815: W/System.err(333):  at gov.nasa.worldwind.ogc.wms.WMSCapabilities.(WMSCapabilities.java:71)
>   02-25 14:36:35.815: W/System.err(333):  at gov.nasa.worldwind.ogc.wms.WMSCapabilities.retrieve(WMSCapabilities.java:40)
>   02-25 14:36:35.815: W/System.err(333):  at com.qq.worldwind.android.layer.WMSLayerType.downloadCapabilities(WMSLayerType.java:146)
>   02-25 14:36:35.815: W/System.err(333):  at com.qq.worldwind.android.layer.WMSLayerType.access$0(WMSLayerType.java:139)
>   02-25 14:36:35.815: W/System.err(333):  at com.qq.worldwind.android.layer.WMSLayerType$2$1.run(WMSLayerType.java:117)
>   02-25 14:36:35.815: W/System.err(333):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
>   02-25 14:36:35.815: W/System.err(333): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:8090 - Connection refused
>   02-25 14:36:35.815: W/System.err(333):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
>   02-25 14:36:35.815: W/System.err(333):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
>   02-25 14:36:35.815: W/System.err(333):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:983)
>   02-25 14:36:35.825: W/System.err(333):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:75)
>   02-25 14:36:35.825: W/System.err(333):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:48)
>   02-25 14:36:35.825: W/System.err(333):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
>   02-25 14:36:35.825: W/System.err(333):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
>   02-25 14:36:35.825: W/System.err(333):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
>   02-25 14:36:35.825: W/System.err(333):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
>   02-25 14:36:35.834: W/System.err(333):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1018)
>   02-25 14:36:35.834: W/System.err(333):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:512)
>   02-25 14:36:35.834: W/System.err(333):  at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:645)
>   02-25 14:36:35.834: W/System.err(333):  at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.WWXML.openEventReaderURL(WWXML.java:444)
>   02-25 14:36:35.834: W/System.err(333):  ... 10 more

How can i show my geoserver layers on Android Worldwind?

Also the globe is not showing properly in Android emulator.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost` from the emulator.

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... Great... Thank you... Very much.. My 3 days time got replaced with good result...

Comment: Would you like to answer this question too? [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735963/why-worldwind-globe-is-not-showing-in-simulator)

Comment: This question is related to globe.