# Why Worldwind globe is not showing in simulator?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, worldwind

Recently I have been struggling with showing worldwind globe on simulator. I have found that on running the app in device it shows exact round globe as expected but on simulator it shows following output.

[image: globeerror]

I am not able to understand why this is happening. Any workaround on this?

I have already put internet and external storage permission in `AndroidMenfiest.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.qq.worldwind.android"
  android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="0.2 Beta">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:resizeable="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"></supports-screens>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>


<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/qworld" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name="WorldWindAndroid"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".layer.LayerManagerActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".layer.AddLayerActivity"></activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" 
      android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
</manifest>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of the Android SDK tools? That emulator skin looks old... You can try creating a new emulator that targets API Level 16+ and turn GPU emulation on by selecting "Use host GPU". http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-graphics

Comment: ok, let me check if it works or not.

Comment: I think it shows in console "Unimplemented OpenGL API CALL"

Comment: 02-26 04:31:02.000: E/libEGL(1339): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API

Comment: No is is enabled and API is also 17, still the problem is there. I think it is because I am not having GPU?