# Generating a random lat/long -polygons in a country?

Tags: c#, geolocation, gis

I have to generate random polygons with lat/lon points within another  polygon
(actually, generate polygons within USA area)
Does anybody know of any mapping API that can randomly generate a polygon within a polygon, such as a country boundary?
Or perhaps how to create through the code (`C#`)?
thanks

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207731/how-to-generate-random-coordinates-in-a-multipolygon-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104908/random-geographic-coordinates-on-land-avoid-ocean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random geographic coordinates (on land, avoid ocean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104908/random-geographic-coordinates-on-land-avoid-ocean)

Answer (score -1):

My first question would be: "What is a random polygon?" Or more precisely "What is a random polygon set?" Random point processes are pretty well-defined. I doubt this is the case for polygons (really curious though - so for the experts, please leave your comments).

- Do you want them to be random in the sense that their vertices are
  random points? - in which case you would get something very jagged
  and overlapping and self-intersecting?
- Do you allow your polygons to intersect in the first place?
- Do you allow your polygons to have holes, and if so is this property random in itself?
- Should any other properties, such as area, number of vertices, circumference follow probability distributions?

Your solution depends on how you answer these questions. I will offer one that is relatively simple using PostGIS (because that's what I know).
The following query creates Voronoi polygons from random points, makes a random selection and merges the result where possible. It can be controlled using two parameters `cells` and `density`, which specify in how many partitions the space is divided and what share of these partitions constitute your result.

```
WITH params AS (
    SELECT
           (SELECT geom FROM natural_earth_countries WHERE admin = 'United States of America') AS geom,
           100000 AS cells,
           0.1 AS density
), voronois AS (
     SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_GeneratePoints(p.geom, p.cells), extend_to := p.geom))).geom AS geom
     FROM params AS p
), voronois_select AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Random()) % Round(1::NUMERIC/p.density) AS idx,
        ST_Intersection(v.geom, p.geom) AS geom
    FROM voronois AS v, params AS p
)
SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Union(geom))).geom AS geom
FROM voronois_select
WHERE idx = 0
```

Note: `ST_VoronoiPolygons` doesn't scale well. You will have to increase RAM for higher values of `cells`

Note: I'm only putting `params` in a CTE so you can run the query in native (postgre)SQL, without the need to wrap it in plpgsql (`DO` or `CREATE FUNCTION`). It might be a bit slower as a result.

Note: prefix the query with `CREATE TABLE random_polygons AS ...` and you got the result in a table ready to add as a layer in e.g. QGIS.

---

**Results:**

[image: USA with 100000 cells and density of 0.1 (10%)]
USA with 100000 cells and density of 0.1 (10%)

[image: USA with 100000 cells and density of 0.02 (2%)]
USA with 100000 cells and density of 0.02 (2%)

[image: USA with 1000 cells and density of 0.1 (10%)]
USA with 1000 cells and density of 0.1 (10%)

---

Again, just one out of a myriad of ways of doing this. But if you want to have more control about the shape of the polygons using the above solution, you could either do this by manipulating the underlying point process, i.e. writing your own `ST_GeneratePoints`, so that points are more clustered. Or you create nested Voronoi diagrams, with the second one having a much higher density than the first one.

Both modifications would yield more compact yet complex "random" polygons.